# Arithmetic billiards, prime numbers and the Goldbach conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, divisors-multiples, arithmetic-functions, billiards

I've edited the following post on Mathematics Stack Exchange, (now closed, at that date I'm suspended) [with identifier **4510963**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4510963/arithmetic-billiards-prime-numbers-and-the-goldbach-conjecture), please let me to know if you've some doubt or I can improve the post.

On the online encyclopedia Wikipedia are edited the articles [Arithmetic billiards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_billiards) and [Dedekind psi function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_psi_function), the online encyclopedia Wolfram MathWorld has edited the article [Goldbach Conjecture.](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoldbachConjecture.html) We consider the following examples as illustration of these images.

I've edited the following images to illustrate the explanation of examples https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3Vgw.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwMGa.jpg

**Example 1.** When I consider a billiard like than the figure F 2, F 3,...,F 5, F 7 I call it a *pendulum*, while that I call *prism* to a figure similar than F 6 where the inner refractions are denoted with asterisks *. In this post we're going to consider simple statements about pendulums inside boxes.

Figure F 1 represents the prime $2$ inside a box, as well as the figure F 2 is a representation for the prime number $3$ with two triggers that are the symbols $\circ$ for the representation of the entry and exit for a piece. For the primes $p\geq 3$ in these figures the greeen arrow represents the distance $D=\frac{\varphi(p)}{2}$, with $\varphi(n)$ the Euler's totient function. The box is a rectangle.

**Example 2.** I represent with a $\bullet$ a joint/bridge between two parts or pieces in our billiards. In this way the figure F 5 represents an application of Goldbach conjecture $16=\text{even integer}=\text{prime }p+\text{prime }q=5+11$ with two triggers $\circ$ and a bridge $\bullet$. The distance to the wall is $D=-1+\frac{\varphi(p)+\varphi(q)}{2}$, therefore you can to think in the box as a rectangle.

**Example 3.** We can represent more complicated pendulums, compound pendulums, for instance the figure F 7 represents the integer $30$ as the odd integer $15$ represented as the left shape **L**, that is the **L** from the figure F 8, and its mirror image. In this way for figure F 8 you've $15=\text{even }+\text{odd prime }p=10+5$ as application of Goldbach conjecture. For the general case the distance to the wall at the right $D$, that's the green arrow, equals to $D=\frac{2k+\varphi(p)}{2}$, in our case $10+52=7$. The box is a rectangle.

**Example 4.** The figures F 9, F 10 and F 11 are for examples of billiards
$\text{odd prime number}+\text{even integer},\tag{1}$
The represented odd prime number is $5$ and the even integers are respectively $10,32$ and $16$. The expression $\text{odd integer }=\text{ odd prime number }+ \text{ even integer }$ is by applciation of Goldbach conjecture, for odd integers $n\geq 7$.

> **Question.** I would like to study the general case illustrated in figure F 11 (see also figures F 9, F 10 and F 12), in a similar way that the examples below. Can you deduce the (shape/dimensions of) box and the path defining an arithmetic billiard for the union (of the corresponding representations) of a general even integer, represented with the generic rectangle with orange colour and a general odd prime number, represented as the shape **L** in yellow, that's **L** is the representation of the odd prime $p=1+\varphi(p)$? Here $\varphi(n)$ is denoting the Euler's totient function. Also is required (if possible) add the formulas that you can to deduce defining your billiard, in a similar way that I did with the distance $D$. **Many thanks.**

In other words deduce a valid arithmetic billiard of a closed trajectory (a loop as in figures F 9, F 10 and F 11) for the (representation of) union of an even integer, represented by a rectangle $2\times n$ with $n>2$ and any odd prime number with the shape of a **L**, as in figures.

You can to invoke the Golbdach conjecture in your representation for the mentioned general case that we want to study $$\text{even integer }+\text{odd prime number}.$$

---

The following paragraphs are to illustate how to deduce more statments from these interesting (I think) billiards, for example the following is for a prime represented with the shape **L**, $p=1+\varphi(p)$, and we evoke a similar figure likes than the figure F8, for example the prime $p=17$, then one can to deduce a statement involving the prime $p$ the area of its representation **L** and the area of the box denoted as $V$. I hope that there aren't typos.

**Claim.** Let $p\geq 3$ be a prime number, denoting $\sigma(p)=\varphi(p):=p+1$, then $\sigma(p)$ divides $\operatorname{Area}(V)−\operatorname{Area}(L)−1.$

**Proof sketch.** We deduce that the following identitiy
$\operatorname{Area}(V)−\operatorname{Area}(L)=
\left(3+\frac{\varphi(p)}{2}\right)(2+\varphi(p))=\frac{p^2+4p+5}{2},\tag{2}$
holds. We get that $\operatorname{Area}(V)−\operatorname{Area}(L)−1$ factorizes as $(p+1)\cdot\frac{p+3}{2}$, therefore denoting $p+1=\sigma(p)=\psi(p)$ we prove that $\sigma(p)$ divides to $\operatorname{Area}(V)−\operatorname{Area}(L)−1$. $\square$

Here $\varphi(n)$ denotes the Euler's totient function, $\psi(n)$ denotes the Dedekind psi function and $\sigma(n)$ denotes the sum of divisors function.

I've flagged the post to attention of moderators.

Comment: Now I'm emotionally bad, I also had to redo the entire post, but please if there is anything I can do to improve the post, please tell me (I don't have internet at home) . Many thanks. I think that this kind of billiards are very interesting.

Comment: The main point of **Question** is "deduce the box and path defining an arithmetic billiard for the union of a general even integer, represented with the generic rectangle with orange colour and a general odd prime number L in yellow colour". Add to the answer if you can to deduce some formula in the same way that I did (for a distance $D$ to a wall of the box). Sincerely thank you very much.

Comment: What is your question? A question should end in a question mark, and there is no question mark in your post.

Comment: I wanted to emphasize the Question added what am I asking in quoted: ...The main point of **Question** is to "deduce the box..." If it helps I'm going to write it in interrogative terms, that's with a question mark. Many thanks for your attention and your excellent answers @GHfromMO

Comment: What is meant by the union of two integers?

Comment: I have tried to edit an interesting (and nice) post. I think my intention and the post was clear. I am shocked by the 4 downvotes and the downvotes on MSE.

Comment: I don't understand the downvoting of the post and answer, because this is a very interesting post. Without a comment, it seems that is not about mathematical reasons since the post is about resarch and I did a great effor in my research and to clarify the post. It has been very difficult for me to discover these diagrams and edit the posts. If you think that the post can to be improved add a comment with your advices and doubts that I will do my best to improve it. I am motivated after it was deleted on Mathematics Stack Exchange, to share the post, and I have the trust to ask for your help.

Comment: This post feels more like a blog post than a MathOverflow question. In order for a MathOverflow question to be of high quality, it's not enough to be interesting. It should also be concise, focused, and _answerable_. As it stands, the question is very open-ended, and also not very self-contained as one must follow several links to understand what it is asking. Finally, I'd advise to get a bit more experience writing good MO questions before venturing into Goldbach territory.

Comment: (1/2) Thanks to God the question is now posted on MathOverflow, and was provided an answer. I wondered about to edit some posts that were deleted from modetators (as soon I know if it is legal, and when I can to by the plugins to edit formulas) in my blog *MathOverture* of WordPress.  It was very difficult @TimCampion to edit it since was deleted from MSE after I was suspended. For edit the post is required many definitions for which there is a lack of competence from my part since my English is bad.

Comment: (2/2) I'm agree  that to provide an answer is difficult for this question since the question is open-ended but I always presume the generosity of the users (of MSE and MO) who provide answers for my questions. The notion of folding a prime like a gnomon  **L** is masterful from my part and I wanted to search help to exploit it. I was inspired in a question that the author formulates in *Física y metafísica del espacio y del tiempo* by Shahen Hacyan, Fondo de Cultura Económica (2017).

Comment: (1/2) The file @TimCampion https://imgur.com/a/bFjMXn0 from Imgur with identifier **bFjMXn0** shows in figure B1 three couples of twin primes $(p,p+2)=(3,5),(5,7)$ and $(11,13)$. As you've said the question is open-ended, I'm agree, but I believe that it is required a *principle* explaining the shape and arithmetic for the boxes, the paths,... (I need to contrast my ideas with other answers) The parameter  $$S'=\left(\frac{1}{2}+2\#\{\text{couples of twin primes }(p,p+2)\text{ in the draw }\}\right)\cdot \sqrt{2},$$ in our case $S'=(\frac{1}{2}+2\cdot 3)\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: (2/2) The scale of tiling of  figure B2 is $1:2$ relative to the figure B1, and one can to tessellate the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with these. The triggers T aren't actived because these are bridges to glue the green and white polygons. The green polygon (the prism) is a copy of (compound pendulum from) figure B1. As I refer this is a thanking message for your attention. Good weekend.

Comment: (2/2 Added) Also is required to determine the parameter height $H$, that is equals to $1+(q-1)/2$, with $q$ the largest of primes in the draw (the largest prime of such couples of twin primes that we draw).

Comment: @TimCampion I would like to add a last link to this comment thread. The link that I'm going to add is for the attention of the moderator who was interacting in comments with me in the post of Meta with identifier **5516** . Thus it will be  a present/award for his friendly comments. As soon as I can to digitalize this I add a the identifier of a link for the file from Imgur with images for a kind of *patched/coloured billiards* (and a graph associated to these billiards similar to the dual graph, that I call the *diagram of carom balls*). Isn't required a response of this comment.

Comment: The images are for the coloured billiards and their corresponding carom balls  https://imgur.com/a/IHVaDM1 that's the file from Imgur with identifier **IHVaDM1** and the file  https://imgur.com/a/SiwyVSR with identifier **SiwyVSR** , many thnsk for both moderators @TimCampion . The figure F8 is miscellany about pieces with which I want to build a different kind of clock (joining both billiards), that I call a *sand clock*.

Comment: There are two **typos** in  IHVaDM1, we must remove/erase the edge (green, green) and   (brown,brown) in the diagram of figure F1, and add the edge (purple,blue) in the diagram of figure F5.

Answer (score -2):

I think that these are all cases, please upvote the post (in the top) instead of this post that I'm answering if you appreciate this answer (I prefer it because the post has -5 of score).

The image with the figures for this answer is this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbUod.jpg, that is the file with identifier **lGMFRZY** from IMGUR.

**Figure F 1** illustrates the case of an even integer (in orange colour) represented by a rectangle of $2\cdot k$ rows and an even number of columns, while that in the case illustrated with **figure F 2** the number of such columns is an odd integer $\geq 1$. In both cases  the blue arrow equals to $D=\frac{2k+p-1}{2}$ and the segments $H=D+2$ and $T=2k$ our even integer that share both cases (figures F1 and F2). You can observe the location of the exit of these billiards coloured with orange.

**Figure F3** illustrates an example for the case with the exit of the billiard placed at the upper left corner of the orange rectangle that represents our even integer, in this case both rows and columns are even integers, our parameter $T$ is the number of rows, $T=2\cdot k$. The formulas are for the diagonal separation $S=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}$ coloured with green, the distance $D=\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{p-1+2k}{2}$ and the height $H=D+2$.

The **figure F 4** is just to illustrate a common and generic piece in the following billiards, the billiards illustrated in figures F 5 and F 6.

**Figure F5** illustrates one of the three cases in which the exit of the billiard that represents our even integer (the billiard coloured with orange colour) has the exit placed at the bottom left of such rectangle with an even number of columns and an even number of rows, the parameter $T=2\cdot k$. The three cases that we study for this billiard are $p-1=2k$ with $S'=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}$, $D=2k+2$ and $H=D-1$; the case $p-1<2k$ with $S'=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}$, $D=2k+2-\frac{1}{2}$ and $H=D-\frac{5}{2}$ and finally the case $p-1>2k$ with $S'=2k\sqrt{2}$, $D=p-1-1$ and $H=D-1$.

**Figure F 6** is an example to illustrate one of the three cases in this, again the location of the exit of the billiard that represents our even integer is the same, but the number of rows is an odd integer. The three cases are for our parameter $T=2k$ that express the number of columns, $p-1=2k$ with $S'=1\cdot\sqrt{2}$, $D=2k+2$ and $H=D-1$; the case $p-1>2k$ has $S'=\sqrt{2}\frac{p-1-2}{2}$, $D=H+1$ and $H=\frac{p-1+2k+2}{2}$ and finally the case $p-1<2k$ for which you've $S'=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}$, $D=2k+2-\frac{1}{2}$ and $H=D-\frac{5}{2}$.

I think that one can provide rigorous proofs when one writes the parametric equations of all straight lines.

Comment: I think that for all these billiards (joining four copies of each one of them, from a specific case) inside the boxes, these can to interact to get prisms with the shape of starred wheels. I believe that the boxes also can to interact in this process but I don't know how to specify it.

Comment: Please feel free to add feedback about the answer, if you want you can to add your answer improving my answer in some way, that I'm going to appreciate it.

Comment: Many thanks for the improvements professor @GerryMyerson (in Spanish Muchas gracias por las mejoras, y que Dios se lo pague).

Comment: Il n'y a pas de quoi.

Comment: I've continued in my home the study of these billiards but it doesn't seem that are being well-received. I tell you if you want to try to study some propierties or tessellations from these. I've studied the shape $\left \lfloor{}\right \lceil$, where the shape on the left is a prime $p+2$ and the shape on the right is the corresponding twin prime $p$ (this compound shape $\left \lfloor{}\right \lceil$ also works for Germain primes $2p+1$ and $p$, and there is a systematic way to fold certain parts of these diagrams,p>3 , in a rectangular box). This is to thanking your attention @GerryMyerson

Comment: Spot on, @user142929!  Keep chipping away at it.  =)